# Backpropagation training stuck

Tags: javascript, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to implement a neural network in Javascript and the specifications of my project would prefer the implementation to have separate objects for each node and layer. I am rather new at programming neural networks, and I have run into a few snags during the back propagation training of the network. I can't seem to find an explanation for why the back propagation algorithm doesn't train the network properly for each training epoch.

I have followed tutorials on a few sites, making sure to follow as closely as possible:
http://galaxy.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html
[image: backpropagation]

Here is a link to the original code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wkrgu/5/

Here is what I am trying to do, and as far as I can tell, here is what I can interpret is happening:
After calculating the derivative values and the error for each node/neuron, I am implementing this function:

```
// Once all gradients are calculated, work forward and calculate
// the new weights. w = w + (lr * df/de * in)
for(i = 0; i < this._layers.length; i++) {

    // For each neuron in each layer, ...
    for(j = 0; j < this._layers[i]._neurons.length; j++) {
    neuron = this._layers[i]._neurons[j];
    // Modify the bias.
    neuron.bias += this.options.learningRate * neuron.gradient;

    // For each weight, ...
    for(k = 0; k < neuron.weights.length; k++) {

        // Modify the weight by multiplying the weight by the
        // learning rate and the input of the neuron preceding.
        // If no preceding layer, then use the input layer.
        neuron.deltas[k] = this.options.learningRate * neuron.gradient * (this._layers[i-1] ? this._layers[i-1]._neurons[k].input : input[k]);
        neuron.weights[k] += neuron.deltas[k];
        neuron.weights[k] += neuron.momentum * neuron.previousDeltas[k];

        }
        // Set previous delta values.
    neuron.previousDeltas = neuron.deltas.slice();
    }
}
```

The gradient property is defined as:

```
error = 0.0;

// So for every neuron in the following layer, get the 
// weight corresponding to this neuron.
for(k = 0; k < this._layers[i+1]._neurons.length; k++) {

    // And multiply it by that neuron's gradient
    // and add it to the error calculation.
    error += this._layers[i+1]._neurons[k].weights[j] * this._layers[i+1]._neurons[k].gradient;
}

// Once you have the error calculation, multiply it by
// the derivative of the activation function to get
// the gradient of this neuron.
neuron.gradient = output * (1 - output) * error;
```

My guess is that I am updating weights too fast or that I am updating them by multiplying them by the wrong values entirely. Comparing to the formulas I can find on the subject, I feel like I am following them pretty thoroughly, but I am obviously doing something very wrong.

When I use this training data, I get these results:

```
a.train([0,0], [0]);
a.train([0,1], [1]);
a.train([1,0], [1]);

console.log(a.input([0,0])); // [ 0.9960981505402279 ]
console.log(a.input([1,0])); // [ 0.9957925569461975 ]
console.log(a.input([0,1])); // [ 0.9964499429402672 ]
console.log(a.input([1,1])); // [ 0.996278252201647 ]
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is a link to the fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/adamthorpeg/aUF4c/3/
*Note: Does not train until the error is tolerable for every input, so sometimes you still get inaccurate results once it reaches tolerable error for one ideal value. In order to train it fully, the training must continue until all errors are tolerable.*

Comment: Can you explain your problem in a manner that doesn't have the prerequisite of knowing anything about neural networks? Namely, could you explain this as a programming problem: what you want to happen and what is happening instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you know about the backpropagation algorithm pertaining specifically to neural networks, I don't know how much help you can give. I will try my best, though. The backpropagation algorithm works by calculating the error between nodes in a feed-forward neural network. In a one layer network, the error is the difference between the input and the expected output multiplied by the derivative of the activation (sigmoid) function. In a multi-layer network, the partial derivative of each node must be calculated as well. My programming problem is that my algorithm is simply off.

Comment: I already did comment on why the question isn't as well-defined as it could be: the explanation of the algorithm you gave in the comment should be the central part of your question above. Remember – SO mainly consists of coding experts and it's easiest to help you on a specific problem if you don't ask us to go to Wikipedia to first figure out what your problem is all about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. The answer is twofold:

First, the network was suffering from the problem of "catastrophic forgetting". I was training it on one ideal value/input pair at a time rather than cycling through each pair and training it one epoch at a time.

Second, in the line:

```
neuron.deltas[k] = this.options.learningRate * neuron.gradient * (this._layers[i-1] ? this._layers[i-1]._neurons[k].input : input[k]);
```

I was multiplying the learning rate and gradient (derivative calculation) by the previous neuron's input value, rather than the output value of the previous neuron, which would be the input to the weight calculation. Hence, the correct code for that line should have been:

```
neuron.deltas[k] = this.options.learningRate * neuron.gradient * (this._layers[i-1] ? this._layers[i-1]._neurons[k].output : input[k]);
```

This resource was invaluable: http://blog.zabarauskas.com/backpropagation-tutorial/

Comment: I was looking at this problem, but it has been many years since i studied neural networks. The only thing I could think of was that your training would always run 5000 times, and that might cause 'over-learning' (or whatever the term is). Anyway, would you mind updating the fiddle with the working script?